# Replacing textarea contents on Facebook works, but superficially

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, replace, textarea

I am trying to process the text in textarea [on 'your' Facebook page, where one can write status updates etc] and replace it with new text. 
What I tried so far: calling

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace
```

or using [Improved sendkeys](http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/) on it like this:

```
$('#'+textarea.id).focus();
$('#'+textarea.id).val('');
$('#'+textarea.id).sendkeys("replacement");
$('#'+textarea.id).sendkeys('{enter}');
$('#'+textarea.id).focus();
$('#'+textarea.id).trigger('keypress');
```

To simulate typing into the textarea. Using the above methods (or variations therof) result in the following scenario:

- Textarea reads: "initial text" (whatever the user enters);
- Replacing textarea contents with either of the above methods;
- Textarea reads: "replaced text";
- Pressing the 'post' button;
- What gets posted is: "initial text";

The process works however, if the user returns to the textarea and adds any character of just moves the caret (it also works for other simpler textareas). Inspecting the html suggest that there are a few elements that store what the textarea has, but the mechanics of grabing the textareas contents are eluding me. *I don't know if this makes a difference, but it's part of a chrome extension's content script*

Comment: Why not use the official FB api?

Comment: @Cerbrus As the extension I'm building is not meant solely for facebook and also becasue a huge part of the project is that it won't rely on any other services/apis.

Comment: You are relying on Facebook to let you post something, already, why not rely on them with the API as well? (I mean, you said you don't want to, but why? you can just write a function like `fbPost("text")` with it, and do the same for other sites you might want to post the text to.

Comment: @Cerbrus obviously being able to target all textareas vs having to write a different client for different types of textareas, greatly reduces the area of application, no?

Comment: @cyphunk, I don't really see the need to write a different client for different types of textareas. You should be able to post the same textarea's content to FB / Twitter / whatever, with 1 click.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's what I was struggling to do, alas only FB is not working correctly.